# MYSQL database deadlock between update and select command

Tags: mysql, database, locking, deadlock, data-synchronization

I am getting a deadlock situation in mysql db. An select query is waiting for the lock hold by update query and the update query is waiting for the lock hold by select query. I am pasting the db deadlock logs below. Could anyone please go through the logs and tell me

1) why update command needs lock on table(server_registry) when it is updatinng only one table(service_status)

2) Why there is deadlock bwteen select and insert command.both of them needs to use different locks. Select needs to use read lock and update needs to use write lock.

PLease help. Thanks in advance.

```
------------------------
LATEST DETECTED DEADLOCK
------------------------
140422 19:49:35
*** (1) TRANSACTION:
TRANSACTION 58C06, ACTIVE 1 sec starting index read
mysql tables in use 2, locked 2
LOCK WAIT 5 lock struct(s), heap size 320, 4 row lock(s)
MySQL thread id 808, OS thread handle 0x36fc, query id 707213 gemsoft 10.127.127.214 gemsoft Sending data
/* criteria query */ select this_.id as id53_1_, this_.creation_date as creation2_53_1_, this_.last_modified as last3_53_1_, this_.server_registry_id as server5_53_1_, this_.service_type as service4_53_1_, serverregi2_.id as id30_0_, serverregi2_.creation_date as creation2_30_0_, serverregi2_.last_modified as last3_30_0_, serverregi2_.is_active as is4_30_0_, serverregi2_.app_context as app5_30_0_, serverregi2_.ip_address as ip6_30_0_, serverregi2_.last_updated_batch_time as last7_30_0_, serverregi2_.is_moniter_server as is8_30_0_, serverregi2_.port_number as port9_30_0_ from service_status this_ left outer join server_registry serverregi2_ on this_.server_registry_id=serverregi2_.id where this_.service_type='MONITER_SERVICE'
*** (1) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 0 page no 595 n bits 72 index `PRIMARY` of table `gemsoft31_08apr`.`server_registry` trx id 58C06 lock mode S locks rec but not gap waiting
Record lock, heap no 3 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 11; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len 8; hex 8000000000000001; asc         ;;
 1: len 6; hex 000000058b02; asc       ;;
 2: len 7; hex 2f00001e7d24f9; asc /   }$ ;;
 3: len 8; hex 800012514eb5acaa; asc    QN   ;;
 4: len 8; hex 800012514eb5e69e; asc    QN   ;;
 5: len 1; hex 00; asc  ;;
 6: len 5; hex 2f64636d61; asc /dcma;;
 7: len 12; hex 67616e657368767961733031; asc ganeshvyas01;;
 8: SQL NULL;
 9: len 1; hex 01; asc  ;;
 10: len 4; hex 38303830; asc 8080;;

*** (2) TRANSACTION:
TRANSACTION 58B02, ACTIVE 151 sec starting index read, thread declared inside InnoDB 500
mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
6 lock struct(s), heap size 1024, 3 row lock(s), undo log entries 2
MySQL thread id 813, OS thread handle 0xda8, query id 707229 gemsoft 10.127.127.214 gemsoft Updating
/* update com.gemsoft.dcma.da.domain.ServiceStatus */ update service_status set last_modified='2014-04-22 19:49:36', server_registry_id=2, service_type='MONITER_SERVICE' where id=3
*** (2) HOLDS THE LOCK(S):
RECORD LOCKS space id 0 page no 595 n bits 72 index `PRIMARY` of table `gemsoft31_08apr`.`server_registry` trx id 58B02 lock_mode X locks rec but not gap
Record lock, heap no 3 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 11; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len 8; hex 8000000000000001; asc         ;;
 1: len 6; hex 000000058b02; asc       ;;
 2: len 7; hex 2f00001e7d24f9; asc /   }$ ;;
 3: len 8; hex 800012514eb5acaa; asc    QN   ;;
 4: len 8; hex 800012514eb5e69e; asc    QN   ;;
 5: len 1; hex 00; asc  ;;
 6: len 5; hex 2f64636d61; asc /dcma;;
 7: len 12; hex 67616e657368767961733031; asc ganeshvyas01;;
 8: SQL NULL;
 9: len 1; hex 01; asc  ;;
 10: len 4; hex 38303830; asc 8080;;

*** (2) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 0 page no 748 n bits 80 index `PRIMARY` of table `gemsoft31_08apr`.`service_status` trx id 58B02 lock_mode X locks rec but not gap waiting
Record lock, heap no 7 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 7; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len 8; hex 8000000000000003; asc         ;;
 1: len 6; hex 0000000584dc; asc       ;;
 2: len 7; hex 160000026015ff; asc     `  ;;
 3: len 8; hex 800012514eb5acb4; asc    QN   ;;
 4: len 8; hex 800012514eb5e253; asc    QN  S;;
 5: len 15; hex 4c4943454e53455f53455256494345; asc MONITER_SERVICE;;
 6: len 8; hex 8000000000000001; asc         ;;

*** WE ROLL BACK TRANSACTION (1)


Following sqls will help you in understanding table structure.


CREATE TABLE `server_registry` (
    `id` BIGINT(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `creation_date` DATETIME NOT NULL,
    `last_modified` DATETIME NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `is_active` BIT(1) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `app_context` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `ip_address` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `last_updated_batch_time` DATETIME NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `is_moniter_server` BIT(1) NULL DEFAULT b'0',
    `port_number` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)


CREATE TABLE `service_status` (
    `id` BIGINT(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `creation_date` DATETIME NOT NULL,
    `last_modified` DATETIME NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `service_type` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `server_registry_id` BIGINT(20) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    INDEX `FK8F8400BC7513AC46` (`server_registry_id`),
    CONSTRAINT `FK8F8400BC7513AC46` FOREIGN KEY (`server_registry_id`) REFERENCES `server_registry` (`id`)
)
```

Comment: What is the isolation level?

Comment: It is set to SERIALIZABLE.

Answer (score 0):

mySql locking system (**for innodb**) works like this :

**FOR WRITE** Write operations needs an exclusive lock on the rows. At the same it takes an inclusive lock on the corresponding parent rows. When it finishes write operation on child it converts the inclusive lock of parent table to exclusive lock.

**FOR READ** Read operation needs only an inclusive lock on the range it got from your index and if index is not proper it will make an inclusive lock on the whole table.

Problem may be when update is trying to convert parent table i.e. server_registry table lock to exclusive lock at that time select is trying to get its lock on server_registry table.

Comment: Could you please explain it a bit more. What exactly is this exclusive and inclusive locks. When both are trying for lock on server_registry table that is racearound condition how it is leadinng to deadlock.